# Could the Avatar theoretically father himself?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

A thought just crossed my mind after a saw [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/AvatarMemes/comments/hhqs4a/so_whos_the_father/) on reddit:

> If I remember correctly the new Avatar is born when the last on dies (I could be wrong it's quite a while ago that I last watched Avatar).

So theoretically, if an Avatar impregnates a woman but dies before the baby is born, could that baby be born as the new Avatar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Theoretically possible, but highly unlikely. According to Avatar canon, the new avatar is born into the next element / nation in the cycle (fire->air->water->earth).

So for the avatar to father himself, he would have to get together with a female bender of the next element in the cycle, impregnate her and then die before the 5th month of the pregnancy (most philosophies that belive in reincarnation of discrete souls/persons believe that the soul indwels the foetus around the middle of the pregnancy/second trimester).

Once upon a time it was also stated that the avatar is born every 100 years, but since it was later revealed that several avatars lived much longer than that (e.g. Kyoshi lived 230 years or so) that was probably just a crossed wire somewhere.

Comment: I don't think that avatars being born every 100 years was ever stated anywhere. That might be a huge extrapolation from Rokku's statement that he had mastered fire a thousand times (and the fact that the avatar era had lasted close to 10,000 years), but that was never a mathematical fact.

Comment: @Renan Probably, or I might be remembering some nonsense from watching a dub or maybe it's just old age catching up to me ...

Comment: Aang was the avatar for over 100 years, so I imagine it's not clockwork.